# Cannot query fromSql method with Entity Framework Core

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I started a asp.net core project, using EF core 2.0.1.
I was able to migrate a database successfully to the project and generated partial class as follows

```
public partial class ManagementContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to connect to the database and get db and get the all records in the db by assigning:

```
var results = dbContext.Results.ToList();
```

However when trying to assign by .fromSql() method i get error:
invalidlidOperationException: 'The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'
The errors is received in both of the following queries (get_results is a stored procedure that returns records of Result:

```
var resultsThroughRawQuery = dbContext.Results.FromSql("select * from dbo.Results").ToList();
var resultsThroughStoredProcedure = dbContext.Results.FromSql("EXEC get_results").ToList();
```

Result indeed has an Id columnm which is the key.
Is there something I miss here?

Comment: What is EF generated SQL for `dbContext.Results.ToList()`?

Comment: It gives you the results as if u query: select * from dbo.Results

Comment: I'm not asking for results, but the SQL query text generated by EF. It definitely does not use `*`, but concrete column names. Since your problem is with column name expected by EF, we need to see what are the "correct" expected column names.

Comment: Got ya
this is the generated class:

    public partial class ScheduledTask
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DeploymentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }